# Deserialize JSON with C# (Multiple Objects)

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to deserialize a School to then insert into a Bar Chart Later. The JSON object looks like:

```
[{"Subject": "TEST APP","AppScores": [{"Season": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","year": "1"}, {"Season": "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB","year": "2"}]}, {"Subject": "TEST APP2","AppScores": [{"Season": "CCCCCCCCCCC","year": "3"}, {"Season": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD","year": "4"}]}]
```

The output I am hoping to see in the `Console.WriteLine();`

```
Subject: TEST APP
AppScores
Season: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Year: 1
Season: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
Year: 2
Subject: TESTAPP2
AppScores
Season: CCCCCCCCCCC
Year: 3
Season: DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
Year: 4
```

I have seen this been done in multiple of ways using similar code below.

```
School subject = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<School>(json);
foreach (var item in subject.data)
{Console.WriteLine("season: {0}, year: {1}", item.season, item.year); Console.ReadLine();}
```

Calling from a Class:

```
public class School
{
public List<SchoolSubjects> data { get; set; }
}
public class SchoolSubjects
{
public string year { get; set; }
public string season { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help to amend this code as I cant find any examples that would do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: formatting has been ammended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your root [JSON](http://json.org/) container is an array, not an object:

- An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).
- An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace).

A JSON array needs to be deserialized into a collection, such as a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If I upload your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/, I get the following classes, renamed more appropriately:

```
public class SchoolSubjectAppScore
{
    public string Season { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolSubject
{
    public SchoolSubject() { this.AppScores = new List<SchoolSubjectAppScore>(); }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public List<SchoolSubjectAppScore> AppScores { get; set; }
}
```

Then your JSON can be deserialized and printed as follows:

```
        var root = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<SchoolSubject>>(json);
        foreach (var subject in root)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(subject.Subject);

            foreach (var item in subject.AppScores)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("season: {0}, year: {1}", item.Season, item.year);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Presume the variables from the list e.g item.season, item.year can be used within a bar chart! Can you help me out with this?

Comment: @TerrorTot38 - I don't know, I'd have to see what you are trying to do.  However, the recommended format for questions on stackoverflow is [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).  If this question is answered, mark it as such, and ask another with the details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have now done this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982984/json-file-to-view-in-mvc-bar-chart-c-sharp. Thanks for your help.