# JSON File to View in MVC Bar Chart - C#

Tags: html, model-view-controller, razor, bar-chart, json-deserialization

I am now able to deserialize a School from JSON, next step is to now insert the data into a Bar Chart using MVC.

The JSON object looks like:

```
[{"Subject": "TEST APP","AppScores": [{"Season": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","year": "1"}, {"Season": "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB","year": "2"}]}, {"Subject": "TEST APP2","AppScores": [{"Season": "CCCCCCCCCCC","year": "3"}, {"Season": "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD","year": "4"}]}]
```

I have found out how to call the JSON file and view in the `Console.WriteLine`.

```
var root = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<SchoolSubject>>(json)
foreach (var subject in root)
{
Console.WriteLine(subject.Subject);
foreach (var item in subject.AppScores)
{
Console.WriteLine("season: {0}, year: {1}", item.Season, item.year);
}
}
```

Calling from a Class:

```
public class SchoolSubjectAppScore
{
    public string Season { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}
public class SchoolSubject
{
    public SchoolSubject() { this.AppScores = new List<SchoolSubjectAppScore>(); }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public List<SchoolSubjectAppScore> AppScores { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help to ammend this to use in MVC and call the variables from the JSON to a list to then display in a HTML webpage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of data your charting library expect ? How does the code for your invoking your charting library looks like ?

Comment: I am hoping to use MVC to view within the HTML webpage. the variables will pass through from one page to another or on the other hand just use a HTML page with embedded C# to do this. Thanks.